# How to detect a flick gesture using UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I heard that [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection) can be used to distinguish between a slow swipe and a fast flick. But I can't find any API to tell the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you specifically need to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, or can you use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` instead? `UIPanGestureRecognizer` gives you precise movement data whereas `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is more basic and just detects whether or not a swipe happened (and in which direction).

[UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a `-velocityInView:` method which returns a CGPoint, expressing points per second, vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score -1):

*You should use Pan Gesture and find out velocity for better accuracy.*

Here is code snip for PanGesture in Swift 5

```
//Add Pan Gesture on target view in viewDidLoad
        let panGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureDetected))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

@objc func panGestureDetected()
    {
        print("Pan Gesture detected!!")
    }
```