# How do I make a UIImageView "swipable" and detect which way it's swiped?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` that I want the user to swipe of the screen. I want to detect if the user swiped up, down, right or left and `println` "up", "down", "left" or "right". Is there any way to make it swappable and detect which way it's swiped?

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** Don't forget to `setUserInteractionEnabled` **TRUE**. Because `UIImageView`'s `setUserInteractionEnabled` by default **FALSE**

You need to set `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in `UIImageview` with [UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection)

[image]

And you can add in `UIImageview` using following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var RightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "SwopeMethodRespond:")
    RightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.imgview.addGestureRecognizer(RightSwipe)

    var LeftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "SwopeMethodRespond:")
    LeftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.imgview.addGestureRecognizer(LeftSwipe)

    var UpSwip = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "SwopeMethodRespond:")
    UpSwip.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
    self.imgview.addGestureRecognizer(UpSwip)

    var DownSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "SwopeMethodRespond:")
    DownSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
    self.imgview.addGestureRecognizer(DownSwipe)
}



func SwopeMethodRespond(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            println("Right Fire")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            println("Left Fire")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
            println("Up Fire")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
            println("Down Fire")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but when I add this to my project the UIImageView can't be swiped anymore

Comment: You need to Set User-interaction Enable my friend. UIImageView by-default it's false

Comment: It works only if I swipe incredibly fast, if i do it slow or normal it only swipes

Comment: Sir that is Apple provide API for detection swipe apple not recognized that your slow motion on swipe Gesture. and bit faster move finger called swipe.

Comment: You can also learn about PanGesture but using pan you need to calculat point as par detect swipe check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html

Comment: Ok, but is there any way to detect the direction no matter how fast it's moving?

Comment: Check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html. and this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487750/how-to-detect-a-flick-gesture-using-uiswipegesturerecognizer

Answer (score -1):

In Objective  C u can do like this,

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *Swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
  Swipe.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | 
                     UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight |
                     UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown | 
                     UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp);

- (void) SwipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
  if ( sender.direction | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft )
    NSLog(@" *** SWIPE LEFT ***");
  if ( sender.direction | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight )
    NSLog(@" *** SWIPE RIGHT ***");
  if ( sender.direction | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown )
    NSLog(@" *** SWIPE DOWN ***");
  if ( sender.direction | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp )
    NSLog(@" *** SWIPE UP ***");
}
```

or a much easier (more code) way,

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];

    // ...

- (void)didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe{

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Left");
    } else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Right");
    } else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Up");
    } else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Down");
    }
}
```